# Could not find method plugins() for arguments [...] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler

Tags: android

I'm trying to add safeargs to my project, but it doesn't let me do so. I have tried every solution, yet still not working. I have tried to change the versions, even the actual navigation classpath and the plugin but nothing seems to work.

Gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    }

    dependencies {
        def navigationVersion = "2.3.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
Gradle app:
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        apply plugin: 
'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.planner'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.planner"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `build.gradle(project)`, add this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.5.3' apply false
}
```

In your `build.gradle(app)`, add this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Try with these plugins, it works for me. If not for you, let me know